# Rails: Access parameters in view after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails 3.2 project, I have a form to create a new site in `new.html.erb` in `app/views/sites/`

```
<%= form_for(@site) do |site_form| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= site_form.label :hash_name %><br />
    <%= site_form.text_field :hash_name %>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="actions">
    <%= site_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then the `create` function in `sites_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @site = Site.new(params[:site])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @site.save
      format.html { redirect_to @site }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Then after the user submits, I want to show the `hash_name` that the user just submitted, in `show.html.erb`

```
You just put in <%= params[:hash_name] %>.
```

But accessing `params[:hash_name]` doesn't work. How can I access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're redirecting to a different action - this will reset all the parameters you passed to the create action.

Either pass `hash_name` as a parameter like the other answer suggests, or just fetch it straight from the `@site` object.

Comment: Okay, fetching it straight from `@site` works.

Anyway, how to pass `hash_name` as a parameter? I tried `redirect_to @site, :hash_name => params[:hash_name]` and then accessing `params[:hash_name] yields empty.

Comment: It is unnecessary to pass it as a parameter, but to do so you would need to add it to the generated route, eg. `redirect_to site_path(@site, hash_name: hash_name)` (or whatever your route is called).

Answer (score 4):

Just append them to the options:

redirect_to @site, :hash_name => params[:hash_name]

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Still `params[:hash_name]` yields nothing.

Comment: Ah got it.. I have to do `You just put in <%= @site.hash_name %>.` instead.

Comment: Try to pass as parameter of @site path.
redirect_to your_site_show_path(:hash_name=> params[:hash_name])