# Passing Params Back to View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page with some filters (a form) in a Rails app. When the user submits, I filter out the data, but I want to pass the params back to the page, so that the filters are still set to what they selected. How can I pass params back to the same page they came from?

UPDATE:

My controller action looks like this:

Sure. My index controller action looks like this:

```
 country = params[:country][:id] if params[:country].present?
    @data = Game.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?", *date_range_array)
            .by_code(params[:code])
            .by_country(country)
            .includes(:country_index)
            .order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
            .page(params[:page])
```

I would like to pass back to my index view the params[:country] and params[:code].

Comment: If you show some code, that might be helpful.

Comment: Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830912/rails-access-parameters-in-view-after-form-submission/12830962#12830962?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set another variable?

```
@filters = params
```

Then in your view you can access @filters[:country] and @filters[:code].